# Do we have to install/deploy parent maven module to use submodule?

Tags: maven-2

lets say we have a ParentPom.xml and there are sub child modules under it; subModule-A and subModule-B. I want to use subModule-A.jar in an another project. If i run "mvn install" command only in subModule-A directory i can install it into my M2 repository but after i define dependency to it from my other project it says something "no parent found for subModule-A". It is OK if i run install command for ParentPom.xml.

Any idea about this problem?

Thx...

Answer (score 6):

You need to install / deploy all modules that are referenced by submodule-A, including the parent.

You can do it like this:

```
mvn deploy -pl submodule-a -am
```

Which translates to

- deploy module submodule (`-pl submodule-a`)
- and all of it's dependencies in the current reactor project (`-am`)

Call `mvn -help` to see all possible command line options

Comment: Just to clarify, the -pl is "dash letter p letter l" and not the number 1.  I typed it incorrectly at first.  My guess would be that pl stands for project list.

Comment: @Daniel project list it is, indeed. I agree it looks like a one in the code font